# Using OpenCL optimization instead of Multiprocessing pool map

Tags: numpy, gpu, opencl, python-multiprocessing, pyopencl

In the first version of my code, I used the Multiprocessing library of python, applied on a main function `MAIN_LOOP` on 16 threads like this :

```
def MAIN_LOOP(lll, seed=None):
    global aa
    global bb
    aa, bb = 0,0
    if paramo == 0:
        C_ij_GG, C_ij_LL, C_ij_GL = np.zeros((len(zrange), len(zrange))), np.zeros((len(zrange), len(zrange))), np.zeros((len(zrange), len(zrange)))
    C_ij_GG_up, C_ij_LL_up, C_ij_GL_up = np.zeros((len(zrange), len(zrange))), np.zeros((len(zrange), len(zrange))), np.zeros((len(zrange), len(zrange)))
    C_ij_GG_dw, C_ij_LL_dw, C_ij_GL_dw = np.zeros((len(zrange), len(zrange))), np.zeros((len(zrange), len(zrange))), np.zeros((len(zrange), len(zrange)))
    while aa < len(zrange):
        while bb < len(zrange):
            if paramo == 0:
                C_ij_GG[aa][bb], C_ij_LL[aa][bb], C_ij_GL[aa][bb] = Pobs_C(zpm, zrange[aa], zrange[bb], h[2], Omega_m[2], Omega_DE[2], w0[2], wa[2], C_IA, A_IA[2], n_IA[2], B_IA[2], E_tab, R_tab, DG_tab, DG_tab, WG_tab, W_tab, WIA_tab, l[lll], P_dd_C, R_tab(z_pk)) 
            C_ij_GG_up[aa][bb], C_ij_LL_up[aa][bb], C_ij_GL_up[aa][bb] = Pobs_C(zpm, zrange[aa], zrange[bb], h[0], Omega_m[0], Omega_DE[0], w0[0], wa[0], C_IA, A_IA[0], n_IA[0], B_IA[0], E_tab_up, R_tab_up, DG_tab, DG_tab_up, WG_tab_up, W_tab_up, WIA_tab_up, l[lll], P_dd_C_up, R_tab_up(z_pk))
            C_ij_GG_dw[aa][bb], C_ij_LL_dw[aa][bb], C_ij_GL_dw[aa][bb] = Pobs_C(zpm, zrange[aa], zrange[bb], h[3], Omega_m[3], Omega_DE[3], w0[3], wa[3], C_IA, A_IA[3], n_IA[3], B_IA[3], E_tab_dw, R_tab_dw, DG_tab, DG_tab_dw, WG_tab_dw, W_tab_dw, WIA_tab_dw, l[lll], P_dd_C_dw, R_tab_dw(z_pk))
            bb=bb+1
        bb=0
        aa=aa+1
        
    if paramo == 0:
        aa, bb = 0,0 
        outGG=open(pre_CC_path[0]+CC_path[2]+"/COVAR_fid_"+str(l[lll]),'w')
        outLL=open(pre_CC_path[1]+CC_path[2]+"/COVAR_fid_"+str(l[lll]),'w')
        outGL=open(pre_CC_path[2]+CC_path[2]+"/COVAR_fid_"+str(l[lll]),'w')
        while aa < len(C_ij_GG):
            while bb < len(C_ij_GG):
                outGG.write(str("%.16e" % C_ij_GG[aa][bb]))
                outGG.write(str(' '))
                outLL.write(str("%.16e" % C_ij_LL[aa][bb]))
                outLL.write(str(' '))
                outGL.write(str("%.16e" % C_ij_GL[aa][bb]))
                outGL.write(str(' '))
                bb=bb+1
            outGG.write(str('\n'))
            outLL.write(str('\n'))
            outGL.write(str('\n'))
            bb=0
            aa=aa+1
        outGG.close()
        outLL.close()
        outGL.close()
    
    aa, bb = 0,0            
    outGGU=open(pre_CC_path[0]+CC_path[0]+"/COVAR_up_"+str(l[lll]),'w')
    outGGD=open(pre_CC_path[0]+CC_path[3]+"/COVAR_dw_"+str(l[lll]),'w')
    outLLU=open(pre_CC_path[1]+CC_path[0]+"/COVAR_up_"+str(l[lll]),'w')
    outLLD=open(pre_CC_path[1]+CC_path[3]+"/COVAR_dw_"+str(l[lll]),'w')
    outGLU=open(pre_CC_path[2]+CC_path[0]+"/COVAR_up_"+str(l[lll]),'w')
    outGLD=open(pre_CC_path[2]+CC_path[3]+"/COVAR_dw_"+str(l[lll]),'w')
    while aa < len(C_ij_GG_up):
        while bb < len(C_ij_GG_up):
            outGGU.write(str("%.16e" % C_ij_GG_up[aa][bb]))
            outGGU.write(str(' '))
            outGGD.write(str("%.16e" % C_ij_GG_dw[aa][bb]))
            outGGD.write(str(' '))
            outLLU.write(str("%.16e" % C_ij_LL_up[aa][bb]))
            outLLU.write(str(' '))
            outLLD.write(str("%.16e" % C_ij_LL_dw[aa][bb]))
            outLLD.write(str(' '))
            outGLU.write(str("%.16e" % C_ij_GL_up[aa][bb]))
            outGLU.write(str(' '))
            outGLD.write(str("%.16e" % C_ij_GL_dw[aa][bb]))
            outGLD.write(str(' '))
            bb=bb+1
        outGGU.write(str('\n'))
        outGGD.write(str('\n'))
        outLLU.write(str('\n'))
        outLLD.write(str('\n'))
        outGLU.write(str('\n'))
        outGLD.write(str('\n'))
        bb=0
        aa=aa+1
    outGGU.close()
    outGGD.close()
    outLLU.close()
    outLLD.close()
    outGLU.close()
    outGLD.close()
    lll=lll+1
    
lll = range(len(l))    
if __name__ == '__main__':          
    pool = mp.Pool(16)
    pool.map(MAIN_LOOP, lll)
```

The parallelized version is located at the end, i.e with :

```
if __name__ == '__main__':          
    pool = mp.Pool(16)
    pool.map(MAIN_LOOP, lll)
```

Now, I am trying to use another method of optimization and I attempt to do it by GPU/OpenCL :

So, instead of this parallized  `multiprocessing pool` code part, I replaced by :

```
# NEW VERSION : with OpenCL

if __name__ == '__main__':          
  # GPU/OPenCL VERSION
  # Select a device
  ctx = cl.create_some_context()
  queue = cl.CommandQueue(ctx)
  # Kernel
  prg = cl.Program(ctx, """
  typedef int T;

  // Extern MAIN_LOOP function
  void MAIN_LOOP(__global T* in);

  __kernel
  void
  gpu_map(__global T* in, 
         const size_t n)
  {
    unsigned gid = get_global_id(0);

    // Call MAIN_LOOP with global_id
    MAIN_LOOP(in[gid]);
  }
  """).build()

  # Output compiler
  os.environ['PYOPENCL_COMPILER_OUTPUT'] = '1'
  # Allocate memory on the device and copy the content of our numpy array
  mf = cl.mem_flags
  # Get kernel function
  lll_np = np.array(lll, dtype=np.uint32)
  # Create input numpy
  lll_g = cl.Buffer(ctx, mf.READ_ONLY | mf.COPY_HOST_PTR, hostbuf=lll_np)
  #Get kernel function
  my_knl= prg.gpu_map
  my_knl.set_scalar_arg_dtypes([None, np.int32])
  my_knl(queue, lll_np.shape, None, lll_g, len(lll_np))
```

Unfortunately, kernel program can't be built, I get the following errors :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):X2_non_flat_GPU_dev.py
  File "X2_non_flat_GPU_OpenCL_dev.py", line 671, in <module>
    """).build()
  File "/Users/fab/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/pyopencl/__init__.py", line 510, in build
    options_bytes=options_bytes, source=self._source)
  File "/Users/fab/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/pyopencl/__init__.py", line 554, in _build_and_catch_errors
    raise err
pyopencl._cl.RuntimeError: clBuildProgram failed: BUILD_PROGRAM_FAILURE - clBuildProgram failed: BUILD_PROGRAM_FAILURE - clBuildProgram failed: BUILD_PROGRAM_FAILURE

Build on <pyopencl.Device 'AMD Radeon Pro Vega 20 Compute Engine' on 'Apple' at 0x1021d00>:

Error returned by cvms_element_build_from_source
(options: -I /Users/fab/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/pyopencl/cl)
(source saved as /var/folders/y7/5dtgdjld5fxd3c1qm9hknlm40000gn/T/tmpg3pfTx.cl)
```

How can I solve these errors?

### Update 1

A similar bounty has bee started about the benchmarking of my code : on [Different ways to optimize with GPU PyOpenCL a python code : extern function inside kernel GPU/PyOpenCL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59024244/different-ways-to-optimize-with-gpu-pyopencl-a-python-code-extern-function-ins)

There are more infos about the part of code which is greedy from a runtime point of view. But this bounty is more about a general idea of what is possible to find a way of optimization.

Comment: I am not sure how many times you are going to ask variants the same question -- you can't run Python on the GPU using either PyCUDA or PyOpenCL

Comment: @talonmies I can't run python routines themselves into kernel code but I can interface extern functions with this kernel code. As you mentionned it, I have already asked for this question and I would like to know today the state of the art about this functionnality. The key point is to know "how to interface C code inside kernel code and extern python functions ?". I can't copy or re-implement in C language all the big function that I would like to call many times.

Comment: My only advantage in my situation is that if I can call in a concurrent way multiple times this big function, the tasks are independent : for example, this is the same thing that parallelizes a loop with OpenMP or MPI except here, I would like to dit with PyOpenCL and benefit from high number of threads offered by GPU. I hope you understand better the problematic. Regards

Comment: I understand perfectly and the answer is that you can't "interface extern functions with this kernel code" -- the basic idea is both nonsensical and impossible

Comment: @talonmies So, as conclusion, there is no way to optimize this part of code above with GPU/OpenCL ?

Comment: The error does not say a lot, mainly that your opencl kernel has errors.

Comment: @AdrianMaire The kernel code is relatively simple since I am just calling the external function `MAIN_LOOP(in[gid]);`with `gid` the global index of kernel, I mean : `unsigned gid = get_global_id(0);`. But `talonmies`told me that this is not a right method  if I want to use GPU/OpenCL, so I don't know what to do ...

Comment: @youpilat13: What exactly do you mean by "external function"? If you try to call a host function from OpenCL, you cannot! (and you don't want to, as this would make all the GPU threads to wait for your few CPU threads). The solution is to finish to execute the kernel, and after, you can make some CPU computing with the result.

Comment: What could you possibly "optimize" with a GPU in that code? It looks a bunch of calls to other Python  functions and then file I/O. GPUs can't do file I/O and presumably they can't run the other Python functions either. All of these questions you have been asking are futile. Just because something is slow doesn't mean you can automatically make it not slow with a GPU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if your host program is written in Python using PyOpenCL, your OpenCL kernels must be written in [OpenCL C](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/specs/2.2/pdf/OpenCL_C.pdf) or [OpenCL C++](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/specs/2.2/pdf/OpenCL_Cxx.pdf). There is no way around that. Have a look at [Numba](http://numba.pydata.org) if you want to write the code that runs on the GPU using Python.

Answer (score -1):

In OpenCL, you have one host (in your case, your CPU executing Python code), and several devices (usually a single GPU).

The Host enqueue operations to be performed by the device:

- Create a buffer
- Save data into a buffer
- Execute a kernel
- Retrieve the result from a buffer
- Some synchronization mechanisms (barriers...)
  [This list is not exhaustive]

Consider that your CPU has only a few processors, usually 8-32 in a current-day desktop computer. But your GPU has many processors (e.g. 4096 cores in my case).

This large difference (32 to 4K) mean that the GPU is much faster for some tasks, but also that there can not be any one-to-one synchronization between a CPU-thread and a GPU-thread. What I mean is, the CPU can launch many threads on the GPU and retrieve the result, but the GPU thread cannot call CPU threads (because you would have 128 GPU-cores trying to call the same core of your CPU, which would be extremely slow right?).

Summarizing: If `MAIN_LOOP` is a function on the Host, you can not call it from inside a kernel. This is impossible with OpenCL, CUDA, OpenGL, or any other similar technology (and will probably remain like that for many years).

What you can do, however is:

1. Call your kernel and save the index for `MAIN_LOOP` in a buffer
2. In Python, wait for the kernels to finish, execute `MAIN_LOOP` for each index retrieved.

But if you are trying to call Python code from a OpenCL kernel, then I am afraid you do not have any other option than translating your `MAIN_LOOP` into OpenCL kernel code.

Comment: @AdrienMarire. Thanks for your help, I am going to try to implement all the content of `MAIN_LOOP` into a kernel code, even including (recopying or adapting) all the little sub-functions inside kernel code (does it need the keyword `static`in front of function definition ?). This may be a hard task to do that but I have no other choice if I want GPU optimization ...

Comment: No, kernel internal functions don't need `static`.